# e.preventDefault() not working on next.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js

Hello guys i am new to react.js and next.js, i tried to paste some data from a form and display it in the console, but once i use e.preventDefault() i can't even submit my form. Is there a better way to do what i am trying to do ? I went for the simpler way in my perspective.

```js
import Header from '../components/header'
import Navbar from '../components/navbar'
import React, { useState } from 'react'





export default function Home({data}) {
  
  
  const [form, setForm] = useState({})

const saveMovie = e =>{
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log("Why i can't see you?")
    console.log(form) // not showing also 
  }  



  return (
    <div>


    { /* header */ }
    <Header />

    {/* Navbar */}
    <Navbar />


    {/*Liste des films */}

          
<form className="form p-10 md:w-2/3 lg:w-1/2 mx-auto rounded" onSubmit={ saveMovie }>
     <div className="shadow">
       <div className="flex items-center bg-regalblue rounded-t-lg border-blue-500 border">
         <label  className="w-20 text-right mr-8 p-4 text-white">Titre</label>
         <input  onChange={e=> setForm({...form, title: e.target.value})} type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Entrez le titre du film" className="flex-1 p-4 pl-0 bg-transparent placeholder-gray-600  outline-none text-white overflow-ellipsis overflow-hidden"/>
       </div>
       <div className="flex items-center bg-regalblue  rounded-t-lg border-blue-500 border">
         <label className="w-20 text-right p-4 mr-8 text-white">Année</label>
         <input  onChange={e=> setForm({...form, year: +e.target.value})} type="text" name="year" id="year" placeholder="Entrez l'année" className="flex-1  p-4 pl-0 bg-transparent placeholder-gray-600 outline-none text-white overflow-ellipsis overflow-hidden"/>
       </div>    
        <div className="flex items-center bg-regalblue rounded-t-lg border-blue-500 border">
         <label  className="w-20 text-right mr-8 p-4 text-white">slug</label>
         <input  onChange={e=> setForm({...form, slug: e.target.value})} type="text" name="slug" id="slug" placeholder="Entrez le slug ici" className="flex-1 p-4 pl-0 bg-transparent placeholder-gray-600  outline-none text-white overflow-ellipsis overflow-hidden"/>
       </div>       
       <div className="flex items-center bg-regalblue rounded-t-lg border-blue-500 border">
         <label  className="w-20 text-right mr-8 p-4 text-white">description</label>
         <textarea onChange={e=> setForm({...form, description: e.target.value})}  type="textarea" name="description" id="description" placeholder="Entrez la description" className="flex-1 p-4 pl-0 bg-transparent placeholder-gray-600  outline-none text-white overflow-ellipsis overflow-hidden"/>
       </div>
     </div>
     <button type="submit" className="bg-regalblue hover:bg-gray-900 block w-full rounded-md border py-4 text-white font-bold shadow">Envoyer le formulaire </button>
</form>


      </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: The code is correct, i tested it and it logs correctly, check that your dev server is working while testing. You can also try to  delete the .next folder then re-create the cached elements with `yarn dev` or `npm run dev`

Comment: i still can't submit even after doing what you suggested, but now i know that the code is right thank you

Comment: That's very weird, is it the only thing that you can't log ?  Are you sure you don't have some errors in your console that halt the execution of code ?

Comment: yes this is the only thing i can't log, i can't even submit the form because the preventDefault() doesn't let me do it, and no i don't have errors in the console

Comment: Hi, the code is behaving correctly if the issue still persist can you replace the onSubmit with  onSubmit={(e)=>saveMovie(e)}. i hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

here is my code which also won't call handleSubmit. I even tried reinstalling nextjs but did not work :

```
"use client"

import { useRouter } from "next/navigation"
import { useState } from "react"

export default function CreateForm() {
    
    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
       
        console.log('submit')
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="w-1/2">
            
            <button
                type="submit"
            >
                sendit
            </button>
        </form>
    )
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).