# Form events not being handled

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, forms, next.js

## ExampleForm

```js
'use client'
import React, { useState, ChangeEvent, FormEvent } from 'react';
import config from '@/config';

const ExampleForm: React.FC = () => {
    const [someData, setSomeData] = useState<string>('');
    const [message, setMessage] = useState<string>('');

    const handleInputChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        console.log("TestVal " + e.target.value); // Doesn't log... 
        setSomeData(e.target.value);
    };

    async function handleSubmit(event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
        console.log("Test1") // Doesn't log either.
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("Test2"); // Doesn't log.

        try {
            const response = await sendDataToServer();

            if (response.status === 201) {
                setMessage('Data inserted successfully');
            } else {
                setMessage('Error inserting data');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            setMessage('Network error');
        }
    };

    const sendDataToServer = async (): Promise<Response> => {
        const response = await fetch(
            `${config.API_BASE_URL}/api/example/postgresman`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ someData }),
        });

        return response;
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={someData}
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                    placeholder="Enter some data"
                />
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <p>{message}</p>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ExampleForm;
```

## ExamplePage

```js
import config from '@/config';
import ExampleForm from '@/components/example/ExampleForm';

async function getPostgresData() {
    const res = await fetch(
      `${config.API_BASE_URL}/api/example/postgres`,
        { cache: 'no-store' }
      );

    const data = await res.json();
    return data as string[];
}

async function ExamplePage() {
  const testData = await getPostgresData();

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <h1>Example Page</h1>
        <b>Test, `example` table content:</b>
        <ul>
          {testData?.map((item, index) => {
            return <li key={index}>{item}</li>;
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>

      {/* Form component used here*/}
      <ExampleForm/>
    </>
  );
}

export default ExamplePage;
```

> **ExampleForm** is in `components/example/ExampleForm.tsx`
> **ExamplePage** is in `app/example/page.tsx`

---

#### The Issue

**When running in dev mode**, the events I have assigned to the Form in `ExampleForm`; `handleSubmit` and `handleInputChange` are not being registered.

Upon clicking the `submit` button, the page refreshes instead *(default action)*.

What I have tried so far:

- Deleting the `.next` folder and re-running `npm run dev`.
- Using `onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}` instead for the form submission.

I am using React, `Next.js v13` with Typescript support.
My Node version is `18.16.1`.

> Also, an extremely similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71897492/e-preventdefault-not-working-on-next-js), but was not resolved.

**Edit**

Above issue only occurs while running dev mode, seems to be something wrong with Hot Module Reload which I can't seem to find any solution for it yet. *(This issue doesn't occur in normal production mode)*.

Below more details that might help:

---

If it matters, on every page in my application, I get the following error:

```
navigation.js:137
Uncaught Error: invariant expected app router to be mounted
    at useRouter (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/navigation.js:119:15)
    at HotReload (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/hot-reloader-client.js:385:46)
    at renderWithHooks (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:10697:18)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:15735:13)
    at beginWork$1 (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17310:16)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19443:14)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackImpl (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19492:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19567:29)
    at beginWork (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25697:7)
    at performUnitOfWork (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24526:12)
    at workLoopSync (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24242:5)
    at renderRootSync (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24197:7)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23339:74)
    at workLoop (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:261:34)
    at flushWork (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:230:14)
    at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:534:21)
useRouter @ navigation.js:137
HotReload @ hot-reloader-client.js:402
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:10697
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:15735
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:17310
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:19443
invokeGuardedCallbackImpl @ react-dom.development.js:19492
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:19567
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:25697
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:24526
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:24242
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:24197
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:23339
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:261
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:230
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:534
```

> This similar error occurs 3 times on page load, at `navigation.js:137` *twice*, and once at `react-dom.development.js:25092`
> *(occurs on any of my page in the application)*

And one more error that occurs:

```
app-index.js:31
The above error occurred in the <HotReload> component:

    at HotReload (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/hot-reloader-client.js:326:11)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
```

Beside these errors and the form submission issues:

- Hot Module reload works properly as intended
- The `GET` request works properly on `ExamplePage`.
- The page does render properly as intended.

Comment: The fact that none of the event handlers are logging to the console but your form is still submitting makes me wonder if the client side JS is actually running or if you're simply interacting with the server-side rendered content. I would dig into the HotReload error and see if resolving that changes the behavior